# How do I use radio buttons groups in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I need to make a group of 2 radio buttons and then retrieve the value of the selected one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply use a `ToggleGroup`

```
RadioButton radioButton1 = ...
RadioButton radioButton2 = ...

// TODO: add RadioButtons to scene

ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

radioButton1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
radioButton2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

// listen to changes in selected toggle
toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldVal, newVal) -> System.out.println(newVal + " was selected"));
```

You can also retrieve the selected radio button from the `ToggleGroup` using

```
toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle()
```

in case you want to do this from the handler of a submit button or something like that...